# DNS delivering ads?

Tags: dns

Could it be that my DNS (which was set by my ISP) is making money when I go online?

I know that the 'web-page unavailable, but look at these amazing ads'-pages (when the user tries to reach the wrong address) bring them a little bit of money. But I am interested in another case.

Could it be that they serve me an ad (as pop-up or pop-down) when I go to a completely 'normal' page without consent of the web-page itself? It would be a kind of add-on, you ask for page example.com/foe, the example.com site serves the page foe, but the DNS sends you unrequested a pop-under ad.

Am I paranoid, or is it happening? Note: I know how to block ads, pop-ups/under and so on. I just want to investigate better how DNS services are trying to make a buck (or a cent) here and there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly. The way DNS works is straight forward; say you host a web server which you have purchased a domain name of noads.com for. When you purchase that domain name you're going to be setting it to point to the IP address of your server. Now, from your servers you can host ads if you wish, or setup redirects so that when someone requests, "Noads.com/hi" they get an ad proclaiming the wonders of a cereal high in fiber. However, at this point you're past the point of DBS resolution. The request to noads.com was resolved to your IP address. The /hi folder was accessed after that resolution took place and your webserver may have presented the ad or redirected as the programmer of the website chose.

As for your ISP sneaking something in there... It would be very bad for their business, if not a suable offense, to add A records to their DNS server which direct you to an IP other than the one registered. To check that you could use www.checkdomain.com to find what the domain should be, and type in the name of the domain you want to reach. Then use a command line (press your windows key and R to bring up a run prompt, then type CMD and press enter) from there type nslookup . This will show you the IP you SHOULD be directed to and the IP you ARE being directed to.

One last parting thought, DNS is not a random function. Meaning you can't set an "If, then" on it. If you request a website it's always going to go to the same IP. The only reason it wouldn't is if there are multiple host records pointing to different IPs for a single name. I don't believe that is something to worry about, as the ISP servers will point to the official "internet" servers which will be carefully tended and kept free of error.

Hopefully this explains everything to your satisfaction. Please feel free to ask for clarification if something is not clear.

Thanks!